# Sending data to API using axios and vuejs and update the view

Tags: javascript, laravel, api, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using Laravel and Vue to deal with an API. I send form data(card details for payment[card number, cvv, expiry date, amount]) and the process is like this:

1. If I post to an end in Laravel this card number, cvv, expiry date, amount, I get a 200 response which include a Transaction ID.
2. I have to send back OTP(One Time Password) associated with the Transaction ID, this requires to update the view in Laravel and provide a field to send the OTP so that the payment will be completed.

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            cardnumber: '',
            cvv: '',
            expirymonth: '',
            expiryyear: '',
            amount: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        updateView() {
            console.log("Update View");
            $("#app").hide();
        },
        onSubmit() {
            axios.post('/process', this.$data).then(response => {
                if (response.data.code == 200) {
                    let transactionid = response.data.transactionid;
                    console.log("Successfull. Txn ID: " + transactionid);
                    // Send OTP and transaction ID

                    axios.post('/process', {
                        PIN: "12345",
                        transactionid: transactionid
                    })
                        .then(response => console.log("Sending PIN"))
                        .catch(err => console.log("Error Sending PIN: " + err))
                }
            }).catch(err => console.log(err))
        }
    }
});
```

On line 26 is where I want to update the view and let the user provide OTP.

Comment: Nested promises are a common [promise anti-pattern](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/) - you should think about [promise chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need additional user interaction, I believe you should add a data attribute that allows you to track the step you are at...

Maybe this helps you...

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data() {
    return {
        step: 'init',
        txdetails: {
            cardnumber: '',
            cvv: '',
            expirymonth: '',
            expiryyear: '',
            amount: ''
        },
        transactionid: null,
        otp: null
    }
},
methods: {
    updateView() {
        console.log("Update View");
        $("#app").hide();
    },
    onSubmit() {
        switch(this.data.switch) {
            case 'init':  
                this.submitInit();
                break;
            case 'otp':
                this.submitOtp();
                break;
        }
    },
    submitInit() {
        axios.post('/process', this.data.txdetails).then(response => {
            if (response.data.code == 200) {
                this.transactionid = response.data.transactionid;
                this.step = 'otp';
            }
        }).catch(err => console.log(err))
    },
    submitOtp() {
        axios.post('/process', {
                    PIN: this.otp,
                    transactionid: this.transactionid
                })
                    .then(response => console.log("Sending PIN"))
                    .catch(err => console.log("Error Sending PIN: " + err));


    }
});
```

you can then use

```
<div v-if="step == 'init'">Show initial form here</div>
<div v-else>Show OTP form here</div>
```

to conditionally show initial form or the OTP form to request the user input and submit it to the server...

Hope this makes sense - don't just copy paste, as I didn't test the code - just quickly changed yours...

Comment: Actually **v-if rendering** is not working in **laravel**.

Comment: It has to be in laravel view like this:
<div v-if="step == 'init'">Show initial form here</div>
<div v-else>Show OTP form here</div>

Comment: You are pasting vuejs code; a laravel view is nothing more than a template engine to output html...   you have to make your question more precise...

Comment: Exactly v-if directive is not rendering in laravel. That is the problem

Comment: It doesn’t need to render “in laravel” because it is vuejs code

Comment: So what can I do then, I think you understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Share more of your code ;-). I understand what you want to do, but I also believe you are not entirely understanding the difference between the blade templates and what is being parsed in there, and where you “shift” to the javascript code...  feel free to share mire of your code and I’d be happy to have a look!

Comment: It works, the problem was that the variable used in v-if was not present.

Comment: Still, however, it would be a vuejs and not a blade error ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the support!